# Is putting a transaction over 1 data changing command necessary?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is it necessary to put a Transaction around Manual SQL commands in c#?

I have the Situation where I have a Long running command which should either do it all or nothing at all in essence. with Manual C# SQL Connections (thus not using entityframework) I'm not sure if I Need to put a Transaction around it to achieve this behaviour or If the commands effects automatically don't occur if any error Pops up during the commands execution.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandTimeout = 900;   // Wait 15 minutes before a timeout
    command.CommandText = "INSERT ......";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each individual statement is already atomic so you don't need a transaction.

Sql databases are - most of them at least -  acid compliant, meaning that they gurantee
Atomicity
Consistency 
Isolation 
Durability 
When individual statements are executed.

Adding a transaction can make many statements behave as one acid compliant statement, but you only have one statement and it is completely redundant to wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: ideal so that it runs in c# instead of directly in SQL should not make any difference.

Comment: It runs on the sql server but is initiated from c#

Comment: ok then there is no difference from running it directly there. thanks a lot!